# Progressive line series animation using teeChart

Tags: teechart

I'm trying to animate line series using progressive line animation. Everything is fine when I add integer values to series X values but when I use floating point values the animation doesn’t go with smooth interpolation in between points. Then the animation of every each point starts somewhere outside the chart panel and not from the previous point.
Is it normal behaviour or I missed something?

I'm using RAD Studio 10.3.1 C++ builder and teeChart Build 2018.26.181203.
I put on the form TChart component and use its editor to add one line series and animation Progressive lines. Sample code to fill series and execute animation:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Series1->AddXY(0.1*i, random(1000));
    }
    ChartAnimation1->Play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added this to the public tracker:
http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=2183